# Is thread-safe comparison operator of two std::thread::id?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, concurrency

Is thread-safe comparison [operator==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/operator_cmp) of `std::thread::id` and `std::this_thread::get_id()` as below?

```
std::thread::id t_id;
```

somewhere in many threads:

```
if(t_id != std::this_thread::get_id()) {
    while(lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    ++recursive_counter ;
    t_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    // ...
    if (--recursive_counter == 0)
        t_id = std::thread::id();
    lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
}
```

---

For example, Boost 1.62 uses to compare threads id:

- `pthread_equal(owner,pthread_self())` for Linux: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp
- `::boost::detail::interlocked_read_acquire(&locking_thread_id)==current_thread_id` for Windows: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/thread/win32/basic_recursive_mutex.hpp

As known [`pthread_equal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_equal.3.html) is thread-safe and `interlocked_read_acquire()` is thread safe.

---

But how can I compare two `std::thread::id` without `std::mutex` in C++11/14?

Can I use for this as below?

```
std::atomic<std::thread::id> t_id;
```

somewhere in many threads:

```
if(t_id.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != std::this_thread::get_id()) {
    while(lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    ++recursive_counter;
    t_id.store(std::this_thread::get_id(), std::memory_order_release);
    // ...
    if (--recursive_counter == 0)
        t_id.store(std::thread::id(), std::memory_order_release);
    lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
}
```

Result for `std::atomic<std::thread::id> t_id;`:

- Linux since version GCC 4.7.3: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OA7R16PCybYctMqb
- Linux since version Clang 3.3: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XBERXFgm1hwwcbNF

Result for both:

```
t_id.is_lock_free() = true
sizeof(t_id) = 8
```

- Windows MSVS2013 (v120):

Result:

```
t_id.is_lock_free() = true
sizeof(t_id) = 8
```

- Windows MSVS2013 (v120):

Result:

```
t_id.is_lock_free() = true
sizeof(t_id) = 4
```

Does `is_lock_free() = true` mean, that `(t_id.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != std::this_thread::get_id())` is thread safe and does not use `std::mutex`?

Comment: What's the purpose of this comparison? It can never be true - `std::this_thread::get_id()` would always be a valid ID, never `std::thread::id()`, since, by definition, the current thread is running.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Something remotely like custom recursive mutex.

Comment: I still don't see the point of comparing `std::this_thread::get_id()` to a default-constructed instance of `std::thread::id`. It'll never compare equal.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I added some of code.

Comment: I see. Yes, `std::atomic<Anything>` is, well, atomic (assuming it's valid - `Anything` must be trivially-copyable; good news is that `thread::id` is guaranteed to be). Yes, `is_lock_free()` returning `true` means this instantiation of `std::atomic` doesn't require locking internally (with `mutex` or otherwise). `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` is not generally guaranteed to be lock-free, but looks like it is on the systems you care about.